# Laravel $request->all() returning null inside the middleware handle function

Tags: php, laravel-5

My Auth middleware in Laravel 5.2 is returning null when I am trying to use $request->all() inside the handle() function.

Here is my route declaration:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth.origin']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::post('identity', ['uses' => 'IdentityController@create']);

});


  /**
   * Handle an incoming request. Authenticates a request to make sure
   * it's origin matches the allowed request origins.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle ($request, Closure $next)
  {
    dd($request->all()); die;
    return $next($request);

    $accountId = $request->input('accountId'); 
    if( in_array($accountId, self::$origin) ) {
      if( in_array($request->getHttpHost(), self::$origin[$accountId]) ) {
        return $next($request);
      }
    }
    else {
        return response('Unauthorized', 401);
    }

  }
```

However, When I am calling the $request->all() method inside my controller, it is returning the array if values.

I am sending a JSON request from the client.

Please help.

Comment: Wow sorry, didn't see it was middleware until now. But if there is any data sent it should appear in $request. Could you just try to add a Get Request to see if it's still empty afterwards? Just add '?key=value' to your address.

Comment: what do you mean by "JSON request from the Client", what does client mean here ?

Comment: 'Client' is the browser here or an API call through another server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access to parameters:

```
$request->accountId
```